# Tense in the subordinate clause when the main clause in the present perfect tense

Tags: tense, tense-agreement, perfect-aspect

Which tense should I use in the subordinate clause when the main clause in the present perfect tense.

I'm thinking about this particular scenario: "I've seen a great nation fell." versus "I've seen a great nation fallen." Which one seems more native in English?

Comment: The vote to close is unexplained. I see no reason to close this question. It is true that the title and question are based on a misapprehension. Surely, what we are here for is to correct such misapprehensions. The bare infinitive is not an obvious feature of Eglish grammar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is grammatical, let alone natural.

This has nothing to do with clauses or tenses. You are dealing with a **bare** infinitive.

> I have seen a great nation fall

A bare infinitive is grammatically an infinitive that is not preceded by the particle "to." One of its main uses is after some verbs of perception, most often like "see" and "hear."

https://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/learning-languages/eng/full-infinitive-and-bare-infinitive-grammar-differences

Comment: "I've seen a great nation fallen" is technically grammatical, I think - would you object to "I've seen a man eaten by bears"?  But it is kind of unnatural and it's hard to think of a case where it would be used.

Comment: @stangdon You are correct, but I have no idea how to make the distinction between a participial modifier and a bare infinitive clear ro someone who has confused a bare infinitive with the verb of a subordinate clause that does not exist. In the context of the actual example, neither "fell" nor "fallen" is grammatical. But I am open to **any** suggestions on how to make your distinction clear to this poster.